# can't I make strcpy after I have done atoi the token?

Tags: c, string, file

Hello I have a problem reading from a file it is organized as follows:

> `id, name, nEst, lat, longi, adress`

I have this in the file.

> `total number: 1`
> `1, aaaaa, 0, 31.00, 21.72, nnn cccc`

It correctly stores the line in the buffer, correctly separates the id but when it reaches `strcpy (name, token);` it gives error, before the `strcpy` I put a test `printf` for the token and I noticed that he saved the information 'santos' correctly so I don't understand why he bugged the `strcpy`, it will be a problem to have done the `atoi` before and now do i have to do the reverse of `atoi`? Thanks

```
void readMainFile(EMPRESA *emp){
    FILE * fp;
    fp= fopen("..\\data\\edificio.txt","r");
    int nEd = 0;
    int id = 0;
    int nEst = 0;
    float lat = 0.0f, longi = 0.0f;
    char name[50];
    char adrees[100];
    char buffer[200];

    if(fp!= NULL){
        //to know how many times I will read
        fscanf(fp,"%*s %*s %d\n",&nEd);
        for (int i = 0; i < nEd; i++) {
        while(fgets(buffer, 200, fp)){
            printf("->%s",buffer);
            char *token = strtok(buffer, ",");
            id = atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            strcpy(name, token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            nEst = atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            lat = atof(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            longi = atof(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            strcpy(adress, token);
            printf("ID: %d name: %s nEst: %d Lat: %.2f Longi: %.2f adress: %s\n",id,name,nEst,lat,longi,adress);
            insertInfo(emp,id,name,nEst,lat,longi,adress);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Sucess!\n");
    }else{
        printf("ERROR!!\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: The code shown *should work* (well, as long as your input lines are perfectly well-formed, but let's not worry about that right now).  Please show us a _complete program_ that we can compile and run for ourselves and observe the same problem you have.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for further explanation.)

Comment: (By the way, you should do this by editing your question, not by trying to cram the complete program into the comment box.  Did you know you can edit your question?  The tiny gray word "edit" under the tags is a button.  Yes, it's bad UI design.  Sorry.)

Comment: It would also really help to know the _complete and unedited_ text of the error you got.

Comment: already edited and put the function, thx

Comment: But you haven't explained what the problem is. "it gives error" is simply not sufficiently precise. What error? How do you test it?

Comment: Thanks, but the function is not enough. I made the smallest possible set of changes to the function to turn it into a complete program that I could compile and run—changed `void readMainFile(EMPRESA *emp)` to `int main(void)`, commented out the call to `insertInfo`, added `#include`s—and ran it on the test input you showed us, and it works. It prints `->1, santos, 0, 31.00, 21.72, rua brasil|ID: 1 Nome:  santos nEst: 0 Lat: 31.00 Longi: 21.72 Morada:  rua brasil||Sucess!` (vertical bars show line breaks). So the problem is in code you still haven't shown us.

Comment: Instead of reading the first line of the file with `fscanf` and tryign to remove the trailing newline with `\n` in the format string, read it with `fgets()` and apply `sscanf()` in the same way.

Comment: When calling this function, the buffer correctly reads the line makes the strtok to divide the string by ',' and stores it in an array of chars 'token' I put a breakpoint just after the first printf and by the debugger I detected that it bug do 'strcpy (name, token);'

Comment: @zwol this is the only function that moves the file

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. ([em português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Giving small hints about the problem in comments will not help resolve the problem.

Comment: *this is the only function that moves the file* — It's still possible for the bug to be elsewhere. In fact, it *has* to be elsewhere, because, like I said, the code you showed us works in isolation.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it bug do strcpy(name, token)". We need you to show us the error messages you are getting, complete and unedited. (I keep insisting on "complete and unedited" because *every word is meaningful* in the terse low-level error messages you're probably getting.)

Comment: I didn’t quite understand how but I managed to solve it through the comment of @WeatherVane

Comment: Best not to mix different input methods, and anyway the last `\n` in the `fscanf` format string is a no-no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Aside:*  I second the comment from @zwol confirming that the code as written is functionally capable of reading the input you provided, and parsing it correctly.

That said, to help in debugging efforts, it is a good idea to code `strtok()` sequences in such a way as to test the return of each call to `strtok()` before going to the next. Using break points while in debug will help to immediately see where the problem is occurring.  Following is your code adapted to do this (and with a few other enhancements and style suggestions):

```
 void readMainFile(EMPRESA *emp){
    int nEd = 0;
    int id = 0;
    int nEst = 0;
    float lat = 0.0f, longi = 0.0f;
    char nome[50] = {0};//initialize arrays
    char morada[100] = {0};
    char buffer[200] = {0};
    char *token = NULL;
    
    FILE * ficheiro_edificio;
    ficheiro_edificio = fopen("..\\data\\edificio.txt","r");

    if(ficheiro_edificio != NULL){
        //to know how many times I will read
        fscanf(ficheiro_edificio,"%*s %*s %*s %d\n",&nEd);
        for (int i = 0; i < nEd; i++) {
        while(fgets(buffer, 200, ficheiro_edificio)){
            printf("->%s",buffer);
             token = strtok(buffer, ",");
             if(token)
             {
                id = atoi(token);
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                if(token)
                {
                    strcpy(nome, token);
                    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    if(token)
                    {
                        nEst = atoi(token);
                        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                        if(token)
                        {
                            lat = atof(token);
                            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                            if(token)
                            {
                                longi = atof(token);
                                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                                if(token)
                                {
                                    strcpy(morada, token);
                                }else {/*handle error*/}
                            }else {/*handle error*/}
                        }else {/*handle error*/}
                    else {/*handle error*/}}
                }else {/*handle error*/}
                printf("ID: %d Nome: %s nEst: %d Lat: %.2f Longi: %.2f Morada: %s\n",id,nome,nEst,lat,longi,morada);
                insertInfo(emp,id,nome,nEst,lat,longi,morada);
             }
    }
    fclose(ficheiro_edificio);
    printf("Sucess!\n");
    }else{
        printf("ERROR!!\n");
  }
}
```